# Temperature drop along silicone tube

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, cooling

I would like to ask your help to calculate the temperature drop of a fluid (at a specific conductivity) that flows in a silicone tube at different rates. This is a real case and I expect to perform empirical tests to determine the temperature from a point where temperature is known to a second point where I need to calculate the temperature but I would like to understand if I can do theoretical assumptions.
In particular, in the system I'm study, the fluid (a solution made by demineralized water mixed with sodium acetate and bicarbonate) is heated with a heater controlled in closed loop with a temperature sensor. The fluid is then moved with a gear pump in an hydraulic circuit made by silicone tubes at different rates (from 100 ml/min to 1000 ml/min). During its path, the fluid is mixed with a particular solution at a different temperature (that I can suppose to be in a specific range). This solution is an infusion of Magnesium, Calcium and Potassium pumped with a peristaltic pump with a speed depending on principal flow rate (from 0.4 to 4 ml/min). At the end, the fluid reaches a second temperature sensor. Considering that the heater is piloted in control loop with a set point on the first temperature sensor, my intent is to calculate the temperature drop at the second temperature sensor in order to pilot the heater with a power that allow to reach the desired temperature at the second point.

I hope to have clearly explained the scenario.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to this community, Michele. That's quite a sofisticated question. Maybe you could add a figure? And what is a PID? A theoretical approach to this problem requires consideration of many aspects of the setup. For example, what kind of flud is this? What velocities are expected in the tubes? What's the friction between fluid and tube walls? Does the mixing lead to chemical reactions (which may generate heat)?...

Comment: I have edited the question with some clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details and plot. To me personally this seems a very complex theoretical problem. It involves the thermomechanics of fluids and mixtures, and also specific experimental knowledge of the fluids and mixtures used. Isn't it easier to experimentally find a table of temperatures at the two points (by monitoring both and varying the temperature of the first) and then to fit a function to it to do interpolation? From the function you could determine the differential heating to be applied at the first point.

Comment: What is the residence time of the fluid that moves from Temperature Sensor 1 to the mixing point?  If very short, you can assume no temperature drop.  If long, you will have to estimate the heat transfer out of the silicone tube.

Comment: From experimental data, with a flow rate of 600 ml/min I have misured a drop of about 1.4 °C between sensor 1 and sensor 2.  All the hydraulic circuit should be at room 
environmental temperature.